# Power function in c language returns the cube and square of integer type 5, 124 & 24 in vVS code

Tags: c

I wrote a code to check whether the numbers are palindrome or not but my code return that 153 is not a             palindrome number then i check out the problem then i found that in VS code the power function return the     square of 5 is 24 and cube is 124 and errors for many other numbers*/

```
/*#include<stdio.h> 
  #include<conio.h> 
  #include<math.h> 
  int main () {
  int a,cube,square;
  printf("Enter the number\t");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    cube = pow(a,3);
    square = pow(a,2);
    printf("\nThe cube of your number is %d",cube);
    printf("\nThe square of your number is %d",square);


    return 0;
    }
   */
   /*
      OUTPUT IS:
      Enter the number        5

      The cube of your number is 124
      The square of your number is 24
   */
```

Comment: `pow` takes and returns `double`s, not `int`s. Try using the right types, as well as the right printing type in printf (as `%d` is for ints).

Comment: If you must use `pow()` with integers I suggest `cube = (int)round(pow(a,3));` Please see [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) Bear in mind too, that your limit here will be 1290³ before integer overflow.

Comment: why is everything put inside comment blocks